Search in multiple nested objects
I need to perform a search comparing fields of two nested objects, the search is done by editorials.name, I need to compare the ID of the object found in the documents and compare it with the IDs of the objects contained in the jobs array so that only documents are returned where the active field of jobs with the respective ID is true
Example of a simple query:
GET csepr-journalist-index-clone/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "editorials",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "editorials.name.keyword": [
                  "[Animais] Pets"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Example of a document that should not be returned because the job that corresponds to the jobId found with editorial.name has the active field = false
{
          "id" : "bbbe9009-e6db-4719-bf1d-e40b0615e102",
          "firstName" : "Alef",
          "lastName" : "Souza",
          "fullName" : "Alef Souza",
          "isBigPress" : true,
          "ranking" : 1,
          "gender" : "M",
          "updatedDate" : "2024-08-05T14:54:34.3809237+00:00",
          "active" : true,
          "jobs" : [
            {
              "actual" : true,
              "country" : "Brasil",
              "columnProgram" : "Teste Cse",
              "mediaVehicleFrequency" : "2 vezes por semana",
              "mediaVehicleName" : "Cse",
              "mediaVehicleContacts" : [ ],
              "isBigPress" : true,
              "columnProgramId" : "c6e6c728-3e6e-475a-87b2-895da3c67d01",
              "mediaVehicleId" : "9b6db888-3f81-40c9-bac0-45d70adbbcac",
              "mediaVehicleSpecialization" : "Teste Cse",
              "id" : "cc608fd5-adec-409e-b4e3-5da276f40f57",
              "mediaVehicleCityState" : "São Paulo, SP",
              "mediaVehicleTypeId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "mediaVehicleType" : "Internet",
              "contacts" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "actual" : false,
              "country" : "Brasil",
              "columnProgram" : "Cse inativo",
              "mediaVehicleFrequency" : "5 vezes por semana",
              "mediaVehicleName" : "Cse jobs Inativos",
              "mediaVehicleContacts" : [ ],
              "isBigPress" : false,
              "columnProgramId" : "92e95a0f-ee0c-4066-8d33-9e9779b0efe7",
              "mediaVehicleId" : "4174f4a2-b670-4847-8c9e-12528148e9d6",
              "id" : "5d16a772-15c5-412a-aa96-e61df00c3af1",
              "mediaVehicleCityState" : "São Paulo, SP",
              "mediaVehicleTypeId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "mediaVehicleType" : "Internet",
              "contacts" : [ ]
            }
          ],
          "editorials" : [
            {
              "jobId" : "cc608fd5-adec-409e-b4e3-5da276f40f57",
              "name" : "[Ciência e Saúde] Ciência",
              "description" : "Descobertas científicas, desenvolvimento tecnológico, pesquisa e desenvolvimento geral, entidades de fomento, políticas públicas para a área. Problemas sociais, polêmicas ao redor de questões científicas/tecnológicas e afins.",
              "id" : "f2b3aea3-c922-4204-9644-08d715e26fc8"
            },
            {
              "jobId" : "5d16a772-15c5-412a-aa96-e61df00c3af1",
              "name" : "[Animais] Pets",
              "description" : "Beleza, higiene, adestramento, acessórios, nutrição, saúde, além de novidades e lançamentos na linha pet. ",
              "id" : "f3a1ef8b-f0b6-4ead-95f6-08d715e26fc8"
            },
            {
              "jobId" : "5d16a772-15c5-412a-aa96-e61df00c3af1",
              "name" : "[Animais] Veterinária",
              "description" : "[Animais] Veterinária",
              "id" : "9351db37-32b3-4e64-9682-08d715e26fc8"
            }
          ],
          "positions" : [
            {
              "jobId" : "cc608fd5-adec-409e-b4e3-5da276f40f57",
              "joinDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "mediaVehicleId" : "9b6db888-3f81-40c9-bac0-45d70adbbcac",
              "name" : "Chefe - Redação",
              "leaveDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "id" : "7a85488d-0aba-4eb6-c461-08dbae33f3f9",
              "priority" : 1
            },
            {
              "jobId" : "5d16a772-15c5-412a-aa96-e61df00c3af1",
              "joinDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "mediaVehicleId" : "4174f4a2-b670-4847-8c9e-12528148e9d6",
              "name" : "Assistente - Produção",
              "leaveDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "id" : "5ba2b578-c782-4171-c46d-08dbae33f3f9",
              "priority" : 1
            }
          ],
          "socialNetworks" : [ ],
          "cityState" : "",
          "fullNameNormalized" : "Alef Souza",
          "contacts" : [
            {
              "hideContact" : false,
              "contactType" : "Email",
              "value" : "a.souza@comunique-se.com.br"
            }
          ]
        }

Example of a document that should be returned
{
          "id" : "f852135e-76d8-45c2-ad78-759ae4873674",
          "firstName" : "Ana",
          "lastName" : "Karen Munguía Luján",
          "fullName" : "Ana Karen Munguía Luján",
          "fullNameNormalized" : "Ana Karen Munguía Luján",
          "isBigPress" : false,
          "ranking" : 0,
          "updatedDate" : "2024-02-14T13:06:08.0214195+00:00",
          "active" : true,
          "jobs" : [
            {
              "actual" : false,
              "country" : "México",
              "columnProgram" : "Teste Programa Em Dev",
              "mediaVehicleFrequency" : "Diario",
              "mediaVehicleName" : "Diario de Queretaro",
              "mediaVehicleContacts" : [
                {
                  "hideContact" : false,
                  "contactType" : "Email",
                  "value" : "i.gonzalez@diariodequeretaro.com.mx"
                },
                {
                  "hideContact" : false,
                  "contactType" : "Telefone",
                  "value" : "(442) 368-1100"
                }
              ],
              "mediaVehicleHomePage" : "https://www.diariodequeretaro.com.mx/",
              "isBigPress" : false,
              "columnProgramId" : "1e267f48-23b7-4f86-8361-30adecf6c733",
              "mediaVehicleId" : "b364ab6e-ec17-4fc2-b418-08dc20fa49fb",
              "id" : "2404e020-dd35-40c9-a804-7f807dcc8294",
              "mediaVehicleCityState" : "Querétaro",
              "mediaVehicleTypeId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "mediaVehicleType" : "Internet",
              "contacts" : [ ]
            }
          ],
          "contacts" : [ ],
          "editorials" : [
            {
              "jobId" : "2404e020-dd35-40c9-a804-7f807dcc8294",
              "name" : "[Animais] Pets",
              "id" : "f3a1ef8b-f0b6-4ead-95f6-08d715e26fc8"
            }
          ],
          "positions" : [
            {
              "jobId" : "2404e020-dd35-40c9-a804-7f807dcc8294",
              "joinDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "mediaVehicleId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "name" : "Editor - Executivo",
              "leaveDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "id" : "2489d98c-b5de-42f2-c45e-08dbae33f3f9",
              "priority" : 0
            }
          ],
          "socialNetworks" : [
            {
              "socialNetworkId" : "39201985-fa76-4187-bb6a-b9ecdbb7b3f5",
              "hideContact" : false,
              "name" : "Linkedin",
              "url" : "https://www.linkedin.com/in/karenmungu%C3%ADa/"
            }
          ],
          "cityState" : ""
        }

I tried some scripts but was unsuccessful
I need to search for the term in editorials.name.keyword and make a comparison in each document, checking the id of the field with the corresponding name value and compare its jobId with the corresponding job ids and return this document only if job.active = true

You can use bool query for AND or OR logic and combine mulitple queries into one.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html
